# Etag header not returned from jQuery.ajax() cross-origin XHR

Tags: jquery, node.js, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

Why is the `Etag` header not being returned by `jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()` in the following minimal example?

Run with: `node etag-server.js` (then visit `http://localhost:8080/`)

**etag-server.js**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

var webServer = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.end(fs.readFileSync('frontend.html'));
});

var apiServer = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Etag': 123,
        'Expires': -1,
        'Pragma': 'no-cache'
    });
    response.end(JSON.stringify({ data: [1, 2, 3] }));
});

webServer.listen(8080);
apiServer.listen(8081);
```

**frontend.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Etag header not returned from jQuery.ajax() cross-origin XHR</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax('//localhost:8081/')
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('pre').text(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { $('pre').text(textStatus); });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<pre></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page Output**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
```

Where'd the `Etag` go? They're being sent to the browser:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Etag: 123
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2014 02:20:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

(as reported by Firebug)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ETag header present in cross-origin responses will not be accessible to client-side code unless the server includes an `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header in its response, with a value of "ETag".  This is true of any "non-simple" response headers.

From the [CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/):

> > 7.1.1 Handling a Response to a Cross-Origin Request
> >     User agents must filter out all response headers other than those that are a simple response header or of which the field name is an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of the values of the Access-Control-Expose-Headers headers (if any), before exposing response headers to APIs defined in CORS API specifications.

Simple response headers are limited to:

1. Cache-Control
2. Content-Language
3. Content-Type
4. Expires
5. Last-Modified
6. Pragma

All other headers that the client needs to access in the response must be "exposed" via the response header I mentioned above.

Comment: Sweet! That was easy. One of these days I'm going to understand CORS.

Comment: it's not for me, it's for the completeness of the answer

Comment: @WalterTross I've replaced my comment with an link to the spec in my answer.